# Alter baud rate after being certain events

Tags: arduino-mega, hc-05, baud-rate

I'm using my HC-05 (Master) to receive strings from a sensor (Slave). Each string is supposed to have 7 items divided by ',' like so:

> a,b,c,d,e,f,g

But it isn't always received in such a manner. Sometimes it's 1.5 of a string or 2 strings in 1. I have tested the sensor with its native software and others, so the sensor shouldn't be the problem. So I believe it may be a baud rate issue. I tried to increase the HC-05's baud rate to 115200, but wasn't able to test anything because I need to use AT commands at the beginning of the program and for that the baud rate has to be 38400.

Is there any way to change the baud rate for Serial after the fact?

PS: I'm using a Mega 2560 and the sensor has a sample rate of 8Hz.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <SD.h>

String test="";
char aux;
File myFile;

void setup() {
  pinMode(22, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(22,HIGH);
  Serial1.begin(38400);
  Serial.begin(38400);
  Serial.println("To begin capture press any key and enter");
  while(!Serial.available());
  Serial1.println("AT+INIT");
  while(!Serial1.available());
  Capture();
}

void Capture() {
  while(!Serial1.available());
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
    delay(125);
    while(Serial1.available()) {
      aux=Serial1.read();
      Serial.print(aux);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("END");
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: I doubt that baud rate is the problem.  You might be overflowing a buffer, however.  Nobody here can say for sure without seeing the actual code.  Edit question, paste in the code, highlight it, and press ctrl-K to mark the code as code

Comment: If you have a MEGA then why use `SoftwareSerial`? Use one of the several available HardWare UARTpresent on the chip instead.

Comment: Don't use delays in serial code.  If you want intact messages, your program will need to collect data until you find something that defines their end, like a newline.  Bluetooth is going to be packetized so your data will likely be bursty - a bunch of characters then some time before any more.  You'll need to consider the burst boundaries arbitrary, what matters instead are the end conditions (newline or whatever) within your data.  Those could even occur in the middle of a burst.

Comment: Well the sensor I use has a sampling rate of 8Hz so every 125ms it will sample and send a string, thats the reason behind the `delay()`. I wasn't using it before and it would either give me trash or nothing, so should i use `while(!Serial1.available())` since I need to be sure there is something there.

Comment: Your code should be event driven, not delay driven.  As already explained the arrival time and grouping of data *after* the bluetooth will not be regular or meaningful.  Your code needs to look for a condition *within* the data, such as a newline or other end marker, or else your code needs to not care where one message ends and another starts, deferring that to something else (human, another program yet to be mentioned, etc)

Comment: Thanks @ChrisStratton, I was able to fix it by making it more event driven but now there is an other problem. I need to write the strings to a .txt file in an SD card, but if I try to do it in that while receiving the strings it causes the same previous problem. So it has to be stored in an array to be written after I've received all the strings, but the array needs to be at least 480 in size. When I tried this nothing was written in the .txt file, it's probably a memory leak. Any thought on how to fix this? Should I make a new thread?

Comment: I think it would be better if you post your "another problem" as an another question, considering the original question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question, yes you can alter the baud rate after an event.  Just use a `Serial.end()` then a `Serial.begin()` with the new baud rate.

Comment: Though this is not the problem.

Comment: I agree but that's the question he asked.

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Comment: The actual issues are already explained in comments on the question; basically a complete misimplementation of serial data handling.